# How to detect that Xcode test build is success?

Tags: xcode

I write a local server which watches `{path_to_DerivedData}/{build-hash}/info.plist` to trigger running a `xcodebuild test`. Every time I build the app target or the test target, it will run the tests in my Terminal.

Here is a problem. I want to run tests only when I build the test target successfully (`cmd+shift+U`), but it runs

- whenever the build is success or failed;
- whatever the build is the app target (`cmd+B`) or test target (`cmd+shift+U`).

Is there any way to trigger only when the test target build is success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a run-script build phase to the test target, and in it, touch a local file that the local server is watching.